# Eclipse 4.5.1 - HTTPServlet cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to create a servlet in Eclipse Mars.1 Release(4.5.1) and I'm receiving the error: "HTTPServlet cannot be resolved to a type"

I installed apache tomcat 9 and I have jre1.8.0_73.

I have the servlet-api.jar file added to the build path, and that did resolve a couple issues, but research seems to indicate that I now need to set the runtime environment to point to apache.

The examples and posts I'm finding would indicate that they are all for previous versions of Eclipse and the Server-Runtime Environments options are not there in my version of Eclipse so I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: can you please post picture and your class path's status?

Comment: Don't manually add API jars to the Build Path. Tomcat will provide them on the Java Build Path just like it provides them to your web app at runtime. Which project wizard did you use to create the project?

Comment: Vishal: What are you requesting a picture of?

Comment: nitind: I'm using the Java perspective. Is that what you're asking?